# WSO2 ESB builders/formatter with local transport

Tags: java, service, wso2, wso2-esb

How to run endpoint with local transport and use builders and formatters in the same time?
When I run proxy service like this builders and formatters are always invoked (transport is http):

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="contentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/SomeProxy"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

But when I change transport to local builders and formatter are skipped:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="contentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri=local://localhost/services/SomeProxy"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

Is WSO2 blocking builders and formmatter in local invocations?

Comment: Any help for this subject?

Comment: Any answer form wso2 consultants?